# remove duplicate values from different arrays php

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem removing duplicate values from an array
I have the following:

```
$input = explode(' ', $term_single->name);
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```

I got the same value twice

```
Array ( [0] => QA )
Array ( [0] => QA )
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You got 2 arrays with same value, Quick fix `array_merge()` before `array_unique`

Comment: Or you just got the output twice. There's no magic string you can pass to explode and array_unique that would get you two arrays out the other end.

Comment: use array_filter() to remove duplicates

Comment: thank you @MKhalidJunaid that was helpful, multiple arrays!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like that.

```
<?php
$name = $term_single->name;
$input = explode(' ', $name);
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thats exactly the same as my questions, it will work if i marge the array 
**$input  = array_merge($input , $name);**